Error Creating Users Firebase authentication - React Native
I have a relatively simple React-Native app. I am trying to implement Firebase Authentication. I am coding in VScode and in Xcode, I'm running my app on an IOS iPhone emulator.
My handleLogin function works just fine if I use existing users that I manually add to my FireBase Users.
This issue occurs when I try to create new users,
I receive this error:
Error creating account: Error: [auth/weak-password] The given password is invalid.
  const handleLogin = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username, password);
      setLoggedIn(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error logging in:", error);
    }
  };

  const handleCreateAccount = async (username: string, password: string) => {
    try {
      await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password);;
      setLoggedIn(true);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating account:", error);
    }
  };

I'm not sure how to get more information. I have tried passwords with varying lengths and complexities:

THISdidNotWork41!2@
asdf23ASDFlkj(asdf#@#ASDjads(#@)

I found the password requirements here
How do I correctly use createUserWithEmailAndPassword?

'const handleCreateAccount = () => {
onCreateAccount(username, password);
};'
I had forgotten to pass the username and password parameters to onCreateAccount in a different file!

Good to hear you found the problem, Derek!  --- And that type of problem is indeed usually the cause. :)
